# How to resolve property array not found on object of type "AppDelegate" error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post to a user's friend's FB wall with the following code. I'm stuck on this line: **                                NSString *post=[[delegate.array objectAtIndex:tag.tag] objectForKey:@"id"];

**
with the error message: "property array not found on object of type "AppDelegate"

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        //Call the request method
        [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];


        // get the array of friends                
        NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

        // Check that the user has friends
        if ([data count] > 0) {

            NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];    
            for (int i = 0; i < data.count; i++){
                id object = [data objectAtIndex:i];
                [array addObject:[object objectForKey:@"name"]];
            }

            NSLog(@"list of friends %@", array);

            NSString *Message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-posted via iPhone App"];
            NSMutableDictionary *params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            Message, @"message", nil];
            NSString *post=[[delegate.array objectAtIndex:tag.tag] objectForKey:@"id"];

            [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/feed",post] andParams:params1 andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];

            UIAlertView  *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message!" message:@"Message Sent" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
```

Comment: look at your AppDelegate.h, there should be a declared property `NSArray *array` there, if its missing, add it. and synthesize in your  implementation

Comment: thanks. that resolved the array warning. What about                 NSString *post=[[delegate.array objectAtIndex:tag.tag] objectForKey:@"id"]; I'm getting undeclared identifier 'tag' now. thanks

Comment: You also have two arrays called array. I would recommend naming them something a little more helpful

Comment: you have to declare that tag, like `int tag`  and the .tag, i believe its a mistype.

Comment: What is tag? and does it have a tag property?

Comment: that line is from some sample code. I think it needs to be the id of a Facebook friend. The one I select to send a message to...

Comment: Duplicate resp. continuation of http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11646746/how-to-send-an-array-to-a-table-where-the-user-can-select-a-friend-and-post-to-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last 3 days i realize you got problem with get facebook friend in iphone. so i make a demo for you . hope you enjoy this.:)

[Fetch Facebook friend here](http://www.4shared.com/zip/e2At_-0x/FBFriendDemo.html)

Comment: if you have problem to post on user wall told me i will help you currenty i not call thsi function in demo but i write the code already u just call it

Comment: thanks so much! the problem I was having was this code picking a random friend: kAPIFriendsForDialogFeed:
        {
            NSArray *resultData = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
            // Check that the user has friends
            if ([resultData count] > 0) {
                // Pick a random friend to post the feed to
                int randomNumber = arc4random() % [resultData count];
                [self apiDialogFeedFriend:[[resultData objectAtIndex:randomNumber] objectForKey:@"id"]];
      } else {
                [self showMessage:@"You do not have any friends to post to."];
}

Comment: you see in my demo there a array FbFriendArray. as ur app requirment when you get random number call the sendFBPost method.

Comment: int randomNumber = arc4random() % [appDelegate.FBfriendArray count]];you can use this for get random friend index and and this function of pass randomNumber instead of tag.tag

Comment: can you send your code to me on my mail mohit27bisht@gmail.com i will fix it .

Comment: I owe you big time. I sent the .h and .m files over :)